# Visual Studio 2015 full completely offline distributive

Tags: installation, iso, visual-studio, distribution

I'm wondering is there a way to download all external components of VS 2015 (Apache Cordova, Android SDK, Python tools, lots of JS libs etc) to create a complete and offline installer? 
Preferably I want to find a way to create such "distro" automatically (by running 1-2 commands).

I don't have internet on my work machine and googling, downloading and installing all external dependencies by hand is tedious and I'm not so sure that VS will see them after installation.

PS: Rant - previous VS releases that included all software components in ISO were better.